# Does the word "muestrear" exist?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Tengo la siguiente oración:

> *No hay población real de medidas que puedan ser muestreadas.*

La versión traducida debe ser:

> *There is no actual population of measurements that can be sampled.*

¿Existe la palabra *muestrear*? Traté de investigar esta palabra y solamente
pude encontrar *muestreo* y *tomar muestra* en los sitios de la lengua española.

---

I have the following sentence:

> *No hay población real de medidas que puedan ser muestreadas.*

It should be translated as:

> *There is no actual population of measurements that can be sampled.*

Does *muestrear* exist? I tried to search it and could only find *muestreo* and 
*tomar muestra* in Spanish language sites.

Comment: Deberías haber buscado en el DRAE, donde sí está.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Claro que existe y precisamente con el significado que necesitas (relacionado con la estadística):

> muestrear.
>
> 1. tr. Aplicar la técnica de muestreo a un conjunto determinado de personas o cosas.

El enlace a la entrada en el DRAE, de donde tomé la definición: http://dle.rae.es/muestrear

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford, the adjective "muestreado" exists, and means "sampled." However there does not seem to be a corresponding verb.

He encontrado el adjetivo "muestreado" en el diccionario Oxford. La traducción en inglés sería "sampled".

Comment: Check the DRAE. :-)